# Scope in an $.ajax callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, scope

If I am using this code why has the scope changed for the "doStuff" alert?  Is there a way that I can make sure that the scope is my object and not the Window object?

Here is the same code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RW4Ge/1/).

```
(function ($) {
    var c$ = {};

    c$.TestScope = function () {

        this.doAjax = function (onComplete) {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'badurl',
                complete: function (data) {
                    alert('doAjax2 self === c$.oTestScope: ' + (self === c$.oTestScope).toString());
                    onComplete(data);
                }
            });
            alert('doAjax1 self === c$.oTestScope: ' + (self === c$.oTestScope).toString());  
        };

        this.doStuff = function (data) {
            var self = this;
            alert('doStuff self === c$.oTestScope: ' + (self === c$.oTestScope).toString());
        }

    };

    c$.oTestScope = new c$.TestScope();
    c$.oTestScope.doAjax(c$.oTestScope.doStuff);
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to specify the `this` value as the context in your `$.ajax()` parameters:

```
var c$ = {};

c$.TestScope = function() {

    this.doAjax = function(onComplete) {

        alert('doAjax1 this === c$.oTestScope: ' + (this === c$.oTestScope).toString());

        $.ajax({
            url: 'badurl',
            context: this,
            complete: function(data) {
                alert('doAjax2 this === c$.oTestScope: ' + (this === c$.oTestScope).toString());
                onComplete.call(this, data);
            }
        });
    };

    this.doStuff = function(data) {
        alert('doStuff this === c$.oTestScope: ' + (this === c$.oTestScope).toString());
    }

};

c$.oTestScope = new c$.TestScope();
c$.oTestScope.doAjax(c$.oTestScope.doStuff);
```

**Edit** I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashingweapon/S7fZJ/) for this and verified that it works properly.  There's no messing around with an extra `self` parameter or having to muck around with closures to keep your variables.

Part of what you were missing was calling `onComplete.call(this, data)` to invoke `doStuff()`.

Comment: The context option only seems to work when you call the function directly "context:onComplete".  I can't see any way that you can have default functionality as well as callback functionality using this method.  Here is that jsfiddle with the context option http://jsfiddle.net/RW4Ge/2/.

Comment: I know you've already chosen your solution, but please give this revision a look.  It cleanly fixes your problem with `this` without having to use any extra closures or temporary variables.

Comment: I appreciate your help and maybe I am missing something but your example isn't using the `onComplete` callback.  It is calling `doStuff` directly.  If you change `this.doStuff(data)` to `onComplete(data)`, `(this === c$.oTestScope)` will return false.  I agree that your syntax is much cleaner.  If I can get it to work I'll use it.

Comment: If you need to use the passed-in function, then you want to use `onComplete.call(this, data);`  That is the same as `this.doStuff()`, except that you can use the passed-in function no matter what it is.

Comment: Perfect.  That does it.  Thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 3):

I have altered your code to pass a reference to `this` onto the doStuff() code.

```
(function ($) {
    var c$ = {};

    c$.TestScope = function () {

        this.doAjax = function (onComplete) {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'badurl',
                complete: function (data) {
                    alert('doAjax2 self === c$.oTestScope: ' + (self === c$.oTestScope).toString());
                    onComplete(data,self);
                }
            });
            alert('doAjax1 self === c$.oTestScope: ' + (self === c$.oTestScope).toString());  
        };

        this.doStuff = function (data,thisRef) {
            var self = thisRef;
            alert('doStuff self === c$.oTestScope: ' + (self === c$.oTestScope).toString());
        }

    };

    c$.oTestScope = new c$.TestScope();
    c$.oTestScope.doAjax(c$.oTestScope.doStuff);
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: That is good.  The only problem I had with it is that I would always have to add the "thisRef" parameter to "doStuff".  I got around this by added that as an optional parameter and setting "self" to "this" if that option was not provided.  Here is my updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RW4Ge/3/.