# How to pass params to a callback

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the best practice of implementing the following:
I have 3 functions: `manager`, `httpGet` and `onsuccess`:

1. `manager` calls the `httpGet` function and passes the
   `onsuccess` function to be called upon success.
2. `httpGet` makes a request and invokes `onsuccesss`
3. `onsuccess` uses needs params from `manager`

What is the best way to pass and argument from `manager` to `onsuccess` without involving `httGet`?
I was thinking about passing a `params` object to `httpGet` which in turn will be passed to `onsuccess` but I really don't like the idea of passing params to a function that doesn't use them at all.

Comment: I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199231/scope-in-an-ajax-callback-function , basically, you can pass the arguments just as the scope of the manager is passed to the onsuccess function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
function manager()
{
   var managerParam =0;
   //the anonymous function below is in the scope of manager() so has
   //access to all of managers parameters
   httpGet(function() {
      //this function can use managerParam
      managerParam ++;
   });

  console.log(managerParam === 1); //true
}

function httpGet(onsuccess)
{
   onsuccess();
}
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cvs9x5L/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)):

```
data = { cool: true };
var yourCallbackFunction = function(httpData, notHttpData){};

var bakedCallback = (function() {
    var _data = data;
    return function(httpResp) {
        yourCallbackFunction(httpResp, _data);
    }
})();
httpGet.onSuccess(bakedCallback);
```

`data` is the extra data you want to pass to the function.

In your callback:
`httpData` is the data received from request.
`NOThttpData` is the extra data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define `onsuccess` as local function in `manager`, it may use its arguments and local variables.
2. Pass `onsuccess` to `httpGet`.